# How to properly remove a table row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following HTML.

```
<tr id="1">
<td></td>
<td><input class="form-control" value="Extra Data"></td>
<td><a href="#save" class="addsub_MS btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="1">Save</a></td>
<td><a href="#delete" class="delete_MS btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="1">Delete</a></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I am attempting to delete a row using the following javascript

```
$("a[href=#delete]").click(function() {
var id;
if ($(this).hasClass('delete_MS')) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    }
    var data = {
        id: id
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deleteparent.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

This does not remove the row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the `this` variable in a different variable, otherwise your reference inside the `done(..)` function is not the same reference to the original `a` you clicked:

```
$("a.delete_MS").click(function() {
    var id;
    var that = this;
    if ($(this).hasClass('delete_MS')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
    }
    var data = {
        id: id
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deleteparent.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function() {
        $(that).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` inside of the `done` is not the anchor.

`console.log(this)` will show that

You can use bind

```
}).done((function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}).bind(this))};
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the selector be

```
`$("a[href=#delete]") or $('.delete_MS')`
```

instead

```
$("a[href=#deleteparentms]")
```